# Jboss EAP Crashing when trying to start Mojarra

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6, mojarra

I'm having the following issue:

When I download the project from Jazz (version control), build, deploy and run it. The application works fine! Then I make some changes to the java code and try to deploy the application again, this time the server crash when try to start the Mojarra. I could notice that, comparing the log from both runs.

**I'm using:**

JBoss EAP 6.4,
JSF (Mojarra 2.1.28)

- **Log when the things goes wrong:**

https://gist.github.com/alissonssz/1038ee9b572ef96209d95d7f9f9db18a

*PS: The timeout starts from the line 385, and finally throw errors from 504*

- **The first and "correct" run:**

https://gist.github.com/alissonssz/c0c3b9878df0542e5b71743eb15c20f0

I appreciate any help!

Comment: This error : **15:10:06,669 ERROR  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015894: .... Por favor gere esse arquivo usando a tarefa Jandex ant.** means anything to you? Have you modified your faces-config.xml recently?

Comment: @ThiagoChagas, means nothing. And no, I havent.

Comment: @ThiagoChagas, It's like the server gets stuck while try to loading the Mojarra.

Comment: - Can you add the 'meta-inf="import" to the module dependency and check whether it works.. 
- First of all users should not use those libraries shipped with JBoss EAP as they are marked as private modules directly in their application, instead users can use their own these libraries with their applications. 
- If users still needs to use this module then they can use following lines in their "jboss-deployment-structure.xml"

<module name="..." annotations="true" meta-inf="import"/>

Comment: I think that I found the problema guys!

There's a xhtml file, which has the line:

<a4j:ajax event="click" listener="#{editarParametrosGeraisBean.controlarCriterios(filtro.criterio)}"/>


When I try put another parameter or change the type for some reason the server stucks. I dont no why, but i could fix it just leaving one parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your time guys!